# Python list comprehension for subdirectories within numerical range

Tags: python, string, split, list-comprehension

I have a set of directories which are named

```
my/directory/and/its/subdirectories0,
my/directory/and/its/subdirectories1,
...,
my/directory/and/its/subdirectoriesN
```

`N` could be anything from a 1 digit number to a 3 digit number. These directories contain some data which is usually called `MCData.root`, but occasionally called something different like `certain_conditions_MC1.root`.

I want to be able to access a certain subset of these `.root` files in a python script, where I can decide the number to access at a certain time. I was therefore thinking of using a list comprehension, something like

```
DataAddress = my/directory/and/its/subdirectories*/
FileSelection = [myfile in glob.glob(DataAddress+"*MC*.root") if DataAddressFinalNumber > number1 and DataAddressFinalNumber < number2]
```

If I assume that all of the data files are called `MCData.root` then I suppose I could split the string at the end of `subdirectories` and at `MCData.root`, and then take whatever came before the `/` in the central split part, but first this is going to become a very ugly list comprehension and secondly if I want to use data that isn't called `MCData.root` I'll have to manually change the script and remember to change it back again. Not a big deal, but not an elegant solution.

Is there an intelligent way of doing this operation?

Comment: Maybe double list comprehension? `FileSelection = [myfile in glob.glob(DataAddress+"*MC*.root") for DirSelection = [dir in glob.glob(DataAddress) if DataAddress[-2] > number1 and DataAddress[-2] < number2]]`

Comment: Or better, two separate list comprehensions, `DirSelection = [dir in glob.glob(DataAddress) if (DataAddress.split("subdirectories")[-1])[-1] > number1 and if (DataAddress.split("subdirectories")[-1])[-1] < number2] FileSelection = [myfile in glob.glob(DirSelction+"*MC*.root")]`

Comment: Why does it have to be a *comprehension*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited/refactored based on comments

---

Assign the different parts of the file paths to variables/names and construct the paths from them. Will allow you to make paths on the fly.  pathlib.Path is not actually necessary, this could all be done with string formatting.

```
from pathlib import Path

base = 'my/directory/and/its'
dir_prefix = 'subdirectories'
filename = 'q.txt'
n_s = [1,2,6]

dirs = [dir_prefix + str(n) for n in n_s]
filepaths = [Path(base,d,filename) for d in dirs]
```

Using os.path to construct the filepaths:

```
import os.path
base = (r'my/directory/and/its/subdirectories')
numbers = [1,201,3]
f = 'q.txt'
directories = [base+str(n) for n in numbers]
fpaths = [os.path.join(d,f) for d in directories]
```

---

First version.

- Don't use a list comprehension if it is too messy.
- use [pathlib.Path.glob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) to take advantage of its pattern matching
- create the pattern dynamically using string formatting.

The text files in the folders just have the folder name...

```
from pathlib import Path

name = 'q.txt'
n_s = [1,2,6]
pat = rf'pyProjects\a{n_s}\{name}'

for f in Path('..').glob(pat):
    print(f, end='\t')
    with open(f) as f:
        print(f.read())
```

---

```
..\pyprojects\a1\q.txt  a1
..\pyprojects\a2\q.txt  a2
..\pyprojects\a6\q.txt  a6
```

---

Make it a function with root, *directory-number*, and file name/pattern parameters so it can be reused. The function could make use of other nice pathlib features.

Comment: `Path().parent` might be preferable to `Path('..')`, as it doesn't rely on any particular file-system conventions for specifying the parent of a directory.

Comment: It's also a bit iffy to rely on the string representation of a Python `list` to be a valid glob pattern.

Comment: I was wondering about that, how about `repr([1,2,6])`.

Comment: That's basically the same thing.

Comment: I would just be explicit and write `n_s = '[1,2,6]'`. *That's* the string you want; don't pretend it needs to be constructed from a list of integers.

Comment: Is the problem that the string representation is not guaranteed, or that *different* Python implementations might be different?? Or someone uses a list-like object?

Comment: It sounded like they wanted to specify different *suffixes* dynamically - I guess the string can be constructed.

Comment: It's that your code doesn't really reflect what you *want*, instead using a side effect that happens to produce the same result. I would just use a list comprehension to produce the desired paths: `[Path(base) + str(x) for x in [1,2,6]]`, for example.

Comment: I was just going to say that - might as well jus construct all the individual paths.

Comment: Thnx, I am finding it hard to understand that using the string representation of the list is a side effect.

Comment: Not a side effect in the functional-programming sense, but it's a coincidence that list displays look like glob bracket expressions.

Comment: it looks like I don't have `pathlib` installed (`from pathlib import Path ImportError: no module named pathlib`), and I don't have the permissions to install it. `glob` seemed to return a list of lists, but perhaps I was using it wrong?

Comment: @BethLong pathlib was new inPython version 3.4 - I added a solution using os.path.